# How to restore data from a damaged partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I unknowingly tried to change my 480 GB NTFS partition to ext4 from GParted. It did not warn me about any formatting, so i thought the data would be preserved. However, It encountered an error and now my partition is missing from nautilus. Gparted and disc utility show it as unknown unformatted partition.

I want to recover my data now. How can it be done?

Comment: sleuthkit to recover files on the whole...or scalpel or similar to recover individual files on a partition if you just want a fire and forget.

Comment: Can you use fdisk to change the partition type back to ntfs?

Comment: I was unable to change it back to ntfs, no probs, had recovered the data by booting from a live cd.. :) copied it, and got rid of that drive.. :) thanks for your replies.

Comment: Don't forget to close/answer your question :)

Comment: @Huckle Sorry, I checked only for closing it. I only found Delete option. And i didn't consider the status being left unanswered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live booting worked for me. Thanks for the response.